# Having trouble to get JavaScript to set background color concurrently with readOnly attribute

Tags: javascript, button, textbox, textarea, background-color

I have the following button

```
<input type='button' id='BtnEdit' value='Edit' onclick='ThisEdit(this)'/>
```

that use the following JavaScript

```
function ThisEdit(event){

    var eid = event;
    var btnlabel = document.getElementById("BtnEdit").value;

    if(btnlabel == "Edit") { 

        document.getElementById("BtnEdit").value = "Save";

        document.getElementById("NT").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("ND").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("NU").readOnly = false;     

        document.getElementById("NT").style.backgroundColor = "White";
        document.getElementById("ND").style.backgroundColor = "White";
        document.getElementById("NU").style.backgroundColor = "White";      

    }

    if(btnlabel == "Save") { 

        document.getElementById("BtnEdit").value = "Edit"; 

        document.getElementById("NT").readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("ND").readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("NU").readOnly = true;

        document.getElementById("NT").style.backgroundColor = "Gray";
        document.getElementById("ND").style.backgroundColor = "Gray";
        document.getElementById("NU").style.backgroundColor = "Gray"; 

    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, it only change the button label and change the readonly attribute of the input text field (denote by id 'NT') and text area field (denote by id 'ND' and 'NU'). It **did not** change the background color of the input text field and text area fields.

Please enlighten me if the way that I change the background color is wrong or there are other things that I have done wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/u085y5en/1/

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to disable the fields. Why not just set `disabled` to `true`?

Comment: works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/ewwh1pag/

Comment: `eid` is not an event, it's the button element. If you want it to be the event, you should do `onclick='ThisEdit(event)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code seems correct, but try

```
if(btnlabel.value == "SAVE")
{
..........
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: That can't work. He does `document.getElementById("BtnEdit").value = "Save";`.